# How to display Unicode string in with Lua in Cocos Code Ide

Tags: unicode, lua, cocos2d-x, unicode-string

I'm using Cocos Code IDE to create a simple project with Lua.
main.lua was saved in UTF-8 Without BOM and contains the following snippet:

```
local label1 = cc.Label:createWithTTF("長い","fonts/Marker Felt.ttf",32);
local label2 = cc.Label:createWithTTF("LONG","fonts/Marker Felt.ttf",32);
local label3 = cc.Label:createWithTTF("rất dài","fonts/Marker Felt.ttf",32);
```

label1 was an Japanese string which was rendered correctly, as was label2 which was an ANSI string. however, label3 wasn't rendered correctly. In fact, it was rendered like "rt dài".

I had tried to use other Unicode fonts which clearly has that character. Still, I couldn't get those character rendered correctly. What have I done wrong?

Comment: lua 5.1 and lower don't support utf8

Comment: Lua 5.1 does support utf8. I successfully displayed Vietnamese and Chinese characters. @Ngoc: did you get any error messages?

Comment: @deathemperor there is not error message, that's what make it difficult

Comment: @Ngoc: for me it was the font I used. Perhaps you can try with others font and see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue, and i have solved.
I figure out that, the font file Marker Felt.tff include in cocos project is not unicode version. So after a while, i have found the unicode version of Marker Felt font in my Mac PC in: System/Library/Fonts/MarkerFelt.ttc

[MarkerFelt Unicode Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5qxA.png)